# Is pgmodeler only used for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, pgmodeler

[pgmodeler](https://pgmodeler.io/) is said to be PostgreSQL Database Modeler.

As far as I know it is for relational database design, and relational database design isn't RDMBS specific.

So is pgmodeler only used for PostgreSQL? Can it be used with other RDBMS, such as mysql, sqlserver, oracle database?

What part of pgmodeler is postgresql specific, and what part of it is not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is specific to postgresql in the sense that it supports everything that posgresql does : sql extensions ("create table like..."), its procedural language pl/pgsql, foreign data wrappers, table partitioning, among many many others ; and these are usually totally incompatible with other RDBMS.
But the main developper is studying closely an integration with pgloader, which would make such a compatibility a thing in a near future.

If you stick to the pure design features of pgmodeler, "keep it classic" and never go for an implementation, then pgmodeler is somehow universal.

Edit : To answer more precisely, the model is "universal", the code produced when you export the model to a database is specific to postgresql (sql data types, extensions...).